# Cryptography system: same fingerprint => same private key

Tags: cryptography, fingerprint

Would it be possible to design and attach a system to a smartphone whereby a public key cryptography system is attached a unique private key to a fingerprint without storing anything (the same fingerprint always generates the same private key)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating deterministic X.509 certificates?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/61845/generating-deterministic-x-509-certificates), [Deriving digital signature key pair deterministically from an arbitrary secret](/questions/249767/). Also, cryptography questions are better asked at [cryptography.se].